# Check whether a given Instant fits a defined Period

Tags: java, java-time

What we get is an Instant and a "date-grid" defined by a period (which defines the interval of datapoints, e.g.: Every Month, Every 3 Months, etc.) and a start date where we started that grid.

```
private Instant getValidDate(Instant request, Instant start, Period period) {
    if(isOnGrid(request, start, period)) {
        return request;
    }
    else {
        return getNextPriorDateOnGrid(request, start, period);
    }
}
```

An example:
Given are the following parameters:

```
request = Instant("2000-05-02T07:42:00.000Z") //Second May of 2000 7:42 AM
start = Instant("2000-01-01T06:00:00.000Z") //First January of 2000 6:00 AM
period = Period("3M") //Every 3 Months

isOnGrid(request, start, period); //Should return false
getNextPriorDate(request, start, period) //Should return the First April of 2000 6:00 AM
```

I really have no idea how to get this with reasonable performance (its a critical place in code)

How do you check whether a distant future date (given by the Instant) is exactly on this grid, and if not, what is the next past date that was on the grid?

EDIT: I forgot to mention: All times and dates are assumed to be in UTC Timezone

Comment: how do you calculate the next past date on the grid? from the sample data I would say April 1 2000 and not April 2 2000

Comment: i am working on the problem with the OP...April 1 2000 would be right, it must be a typo...i will edit the answer but we will have to wait for him to accept it

Comment: what is supposed to happen if request is before start? also April 1st 2000?

Comment: The case for "before start" will be catched and throws an exception

Comment: @Giovanni the second of april was a typo left over from a previous example. We expect the requested date to be past the start date, otherwise as Abbel said, it will be catched prior to the method execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple test case that should match your requirements:

```
package test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.ZoneId;

    public class Java8PeriodAndInstant2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // LocalDate request=LocalDate.of(2000, 5, 2);
            // LocalDate start=LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
            LocalDateTime start = Instant.parse("2000-01-01T06:00:00.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
            LocalDateTime request = Instant.parse("2000-05-02T07:42:00.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
            Period period = Period.ofMonths(3);
            System.out.println("is on grid " + isOnGrid(request, start, period));
            System.out.println("is on grid " + isOnGrid(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 4, 2,0,0), start, period));
            System.out.println("is on grid " + isOnGrid(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 4, 1,0,0), start, period));
            System.out.println("getNextPriorDate " + getNextPriorDate(request, start, period));
            System.out.println("isOnGrid " + isOnGrid(Instant.parse("2000-01-03T05:00:00.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime(), start, Period.ofDays(1)));
            System.out.println("isOnGrid " + isOnGrid(Instant.parse("2000-01-03T06:00:00.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime(), start, Period.ofDays(1)));
            System.out.println("getNextPriorDate " + getNextPriorDate(Instant.parse("2000-01-03T05:00:00.000Z").atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime(), start, Period.ofDays(1)));
        }

        private static boolean isOnGrid(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime request, Period period) {
            if (period.getDays() != 0) {
                return ((Duration.between(start, request).toHours()%period.getDays())==0);
            }
            Period diffPeriod = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), request.toLocalDate());
            if (diffPeriod.getDays()!=0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (period.getMonths() != 0) {
                return ((diffPeriod.toTotalMonths()) % (period.toTotalMonths()) == 0);
            }
            if (diffPeriod.getMonths()!=0) {
                return false;
            }               
            if (period.getYears() != 0) {
                return ((diffPeriod.getYears()) % (period.getYears()) == 0);
            }   
            return false;
        }

        private static LocalDateTime getNextPriorDate(LocalDateTime request, LocalDateTime start, Period period) {
            if (period.getDays() != 0) {
                long hoursDiff=Duration.between(start, request).toHours();
                return start.plusDays(hoursDiff/24);
            }
            Period diffPeriod = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), request.toLocalDate());
            if (period.getMonths() != 0) {
                diffPeriod = diffPeriod.withDays(0);
                long monthDiff = diffPeriod.toTotalMonths() % period.toTotalMonths();
                return start.plus(diffPeriod).minusMonths(monthDiff);
            }
            if (period.getYears() != 0) {
                diffPeriod = diffPeriod.withDays(0);
                diffPeriod.withMonths(0);
                long yearsDiff = diffPeriod.getYears() % period.getYears();
                return start.plus(diffPeriod).minusYears(yearsDiff);
            }               
            return null;
        }

    }
```

it works with periods of days or months or years.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works as described +1.    But we need a solution, which also handles days (and if possible even takes the time in day into account). The Period will either have an number of days, a number of months or a number of years in it. This means there won´t be any mixed things like "P1Y3M". EDIT: I noticed this was not clear: to take the example from the OP: 2000-01-01T06:00:00.000Z as start with one day as interval should map 2000-01-03T05:00:00.000Z to 2000-01-02T06:00:00.000Z because the value to map did not reach 6:00 at the next day

Comment: @Abbel is right, mixed intervals should not be considered as we simply dont plan on supporting them.

Comment: @Abbel I updated the response with the handling of days and years

Comment: This seems like a relly good aproach, sadly it seems like your isOnGrid() doesnt consider different times, and different days for the request. So the 2nd of April will still be onGrid with monthly interval, while technically it should always be the 1st of every month (If the start-date was the 1st in a month.

Comment: @FelixZett fixed, there was a bug

Comment: `return ((Duration.between(start, request).toHours()%24)==0)` shoud be `return ((Duration.between(start, request).toDays()%period.getDays())==0)`, otherwise Periods like "P2D" won't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much Giovanni, this really helped

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add `Period`s to `Instant`s. They have a different "scope".

An `Instant` *i* simply represents a point in the timeline, counting the amount of millis/nanos from a specific point in time called "Epoch".
At this instant *i*, the time at the clock at the wall (even the date in a calendar) differs around the world. It depends on the timezone you are in.

A `Period` respects different lengths of its representation among different timezones starting at differnt dates. For example: A month lasts 30 days in June but 31 days in August. And it is even more complex if daylight saving shifts occur.
An `Instant` has no idea, what a "month" actually is. You can parse it from a `String` and output it to it, but internally it does not represent a human understandable form of a month  like 'Jan', 'Feb', ... .

This is, why you have to align an `Instant` to a `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` using a `ZoneId` or an `ZoneOffset`. Theses classes understand and can work with `Period`s.

The following code converts your `Instant`s to `LocalDateTime`s to take into account the above comments:

```
private static Instant getValidDate2(Instant request, Instant start, Period period)
{
    assert(!request.isBefore(start));

    // multiplication of period only works with days exclusive or
    // zero daypart of period
    assert(period.getDays() == 0 || (period.getMonths() == 0 && period.getYears() == 0));

    ZoneId utcZone = ZoneOffset.UTC;

    LocalDateTime ldstart = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(start, utcZone);
    LocalDateTime ldreq = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(request, utcZone);

    // calculate an approximation of how many periods have to be applied to get near request
    Duration simpleDuration = Duration.between(ldstart, ldstart.plus(period));
    Duration durationToReq = Duration.between(ldstart, ldreq);
    int factor = (int) (durationToReq.toDays() / simpleDuration.toDays()); // rough approximation

    // go near to request by a multiple of period 
    Period jump = Period.of(period.getYears() * factor, period.getMonths() * factor, period.getDays() * factor);
    LocalDateTime ldRunning = ldstart.plus(jump);

    // make sure ldRunning < request
    while (ldRunning.isAfter(ldreq)) {
        ldRunning = ldRunning.minus(period);
    }

    // make sure we pass request and 
    // save the the last date before or equal to request on the grid
    LocalDateTime ldLastbefore = ldRunning;
    while (!ldRunning.isAfter(ldreq)) {            
        ldLastbefore = ldRunning;
        ldRunning = ldRunning.plus(period);
    }

    return ldLastbefore.equals(ldreq) ? request : ldLastbefore.atZone(utcZone).toInstant();
}
```

Explanation:
To avoid a loop adding `period` until it gets to `request`, a rough approximation is done on how often `period` must be added to `start` to come to `request`. A new period being a multiple of the request `period` is then added and aligned to get the last value of the grid which is less or equal to `request`. Depending on a comparation between the last value and `request`, the according instant is returned. In fact, the check is useless besides the fact, that `request == request` when it was on the grid and not only `equal`.

Here you can find further informations about java time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/index.html

Comment: I forgot to add, for simplicity we can assume, all times and dates here are given in UTC zone format, so I think it should actually be possible to add a period to an instant.

Comment: Then semantically it is not an `Instant` but a `ZonedDateTime` ;-) If you try to add a `Period` to an `Instant` using the plus method you will get an Exception.